# Token validation not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, backend

I'm working on a php library that provides to make easier the token authentication with various automations.

The problem is that when I try to validate the token sometimes it works and sometimes not, the function start a pdo connection to the database and take the token row, than if the row is 1 check expiration (token_timestamp > time()) and if used is false (0)

Code below.

The function

```
public function validate($token) {
    $db = $this->connect();

    if ($token == '' || empty($token) || !isset($token)) {
        $token = $this->Token["token"];
    }

    $q = $db->pQuery("SELECT * FROM {$this->DBTable} WHERE `token`={$token}", []);

    if ($q->fetch()) {
        # THE STRING EXISTS

        $r = $q->fetch();

        if ($r["expiration"] > time() && isset($r) && $r !== false) {
            if ($r["used"] == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("This token ($token) has been already used");
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("EXPIRED TOKEN ($token) at: {$r["expiration"]}");
        }
    }
    throw new \Exception("INVALID TOKEN");
}
```

**The database class**

```
namespace TokenLogin\Classes;

use \PDO as PDO;

class Database {

    # Database Host
    public $Host = "";

    # Database Username
    public $User = "";

    # Database Password
    public $Passwd = "";

    # Database Name
    public $Name = "";

    # Database Port
    public $Port = "";

    # Table name
    public $Table = "";

    # The Connection
    protected $conn = "";

    function __construct()
    {
        settype($this->Table, 'string');
        settype($this->Port, 'int');
    }

    public function setConnection($data) {
        # THIS SHOULD SET PARAMETERS
        if (is_array($data) && count($data) == 6) {
            $this->Host = $data["host"];
            $this->Port = $data["port"];
            $this->Name = $data["name"];
            $this->User = $data["user"];
            $this->Passwd = $data["pass"];
            $this->Table = $data["table"];

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    function __clone() {}

    /**
     * Connect to the databse
     * @return bool|PDO|string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function connect() {
        # Try to connect and return the connection
        try {
            $conn = $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->Host . ";port=" . $this->Port . ";dbname=" . $this->Name, $this->User, $this->Passwd);
            return ($conn === $this->conn) ? $this->conn : false;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the connection
     * @return bool
     */
    public function destroy() {
        $this->conn = null;
        return $this->conn === null;
    }


    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param array $params
     * @return bool|\PDOStatement
     */
    public function pQuery($sql, $params = []) {
        if (is_array($params) && is_string($sql)) {

            $conn = $this->connect();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

            # Safe query
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return $stmt;

        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get table name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->Table;
    }


    /**
     * Set table name.
     * @param $table
     * @return bool
     */
    public function setTable($table)
    {
        $this->Table = $table;
        $this->connect()->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$this->Table` (
              `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `user` varchar(255),
              `token` varchar(255),
              `creation` int(99),
              `expiration` int(99),
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");
        $this->destroy();
        return $this->Table == $table;
    }
}
```

**Token generation function**:

```
public function newToken($len = 4, $expiration = 5)
    {
        $token = $this->_random($len);
        $expiration = strtotime("+ $expiration minutes");
        $creation = time();

        $this->Token = [
            "token" => $token,
            "expiration" => $expiration,
            "creation" => $creation
        ];

        return $this->Token;
    }
```

Comment: Expiration returns timestamp

Comment: `expiration int(99)` why is this not a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP column

Comment: How do you set `expiration` show us that code

Comment: I'm new in sql and I didn't know that exists a timestamp parameter... can this solve?

Comment: Yes probably as `time()` returns a timestamp, therefore the test will be testing like values